# Iterate two list simultaneously in foreach in mybatis

Tags: foreach, mybatis

I want to find records which matches with the particular month and year combination.

If I provide number of months 3 , it query should take past three months like these.

Select * from table
where (month = August and year = 2017 ) or (month = July and year = 2017) or (month = June and year = 2017)

```
<select id="getAll" parameterType="list" resultType="test">
Select * from table where      
<foreach item="month"  index="key" collection="months" separator=" OR " open="(" close=")">
            month  = #{month} AND year = #{years[ (${key}) ]}
        </foreach>
</select>
```

I have list of months {August, July , June} and list of years {2017,2017,2017}.

How can I use foreach of mybatis to achieve above results.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the example but, it would be possible to implement nested 'for each' elements?

```
<select id="getOred" parameterType="list" resultType="test">
Select * from table where
     <foreach item="month" index="mkey" collection="months" open="(" separator=" OR " close=")">
        <foreach item="year" index="ykey" collection="years" open="" separator="" close="">
            <if test="mkey == ykey">
                month = #{month} AND year = #{year}
            </if>
        </foreach>
    </foreach>
```